# Force SWFObject to use EMBED instead of OBJECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, google-chrome, swfobject

Is it possible to force SWFobject to embed flash using the `embed` tag instead of the default `object` tag? Right now I’m using this:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(url, 'player', width, height, "8", null, null, params, attrs)
```

This results in something like:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="player" data="/player.swf">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

But I would like to embed using `embed` instead for Chrome, as I suspect that I can solve some of chromes mysterious flash bugs, such as position:fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: nope.

A key goal for SWFObject 2.x was to [avoid using the `embed` tag](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashembedcagematch/), as it isn't a standard in HTML 4 or XHTML, and doesn't support fallback content.  Therefore, there is no `embed` option in SWFObject 2.  (FWIW, SWFObject 2.x predates HTML5 and the codification of `embed` as a standard.)

You could try using [SWFObject 1.5](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-examples/source/browse/trunk/scripts/swfobject-1.5.js?r=44), which used `embed` for IE and `object` for everything else, but you'd have to modify the source code to add a fork for Chrome.

Here's what I'd do if I were in your shoes:

1. Try the [SWFObject 2.3 beta](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/blob/master/swfobject/src/swfobject.js). It still uses the `object` element, but has many updates.
2. Try hand-coding an embed tag to see if it fixes your issues. There's some sample code in [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashembedcagematch/) that you can modify to suit your needs.